# PhantomJS 2.1 - Global error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ember at http://localhost:4221/1400/tests/index.html?hidepassed

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

PhantomJS 2.1 - Global error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ember at http://localhost:4221/1400/tests/index.html?hidepassed

Here is my result of 
[ember version --verbose && npm --version && yarn --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBMxa.png)

Comment: I'm afraid without a complete stacktrace this is impossible to debug 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback @TBieniek. I have figured out the answer after digging deep into the tests/index.html file.

I have used rootURL inside my tests/index.html file. But i haven't defined any value for rootURL inside my environment.js file.